# Encontrar una clave dentro de un diccionario por medio de un valor

Tags: python, python-3.x

me gustaria poder encontrar una clave dentro de un diccionario por medio de un valor ingresado. El ejemplo es el siguiente.

```
diccionario = {'jorge' : 1, 'andrea' : 4}

buscar = int(input("Introduce numero: "))

for nombre, numero in diccionario.items():
    if numero == buscar:
        print(nombre)
```

El ejemplo anterior funciona correctamente, le introducimos un numero y si coincide con un valor de una de las claves que estan dentro del diccionario nos devuelve el nombre de la clave, pero si yo en lugar de un valor le asigno varios valores a cada una de las claves por medio de una lista como por ejemplo el siguiente caso.

```
diccionario = {'jorge' : [1,2,3] , 'andrea' : [4,5,6]}

    buscar = int(input("Introduce numero: "))

    for nombre, numero in diccionario.items():
        if numero == buscar:
            print(nombre)
```

El mismo procedimiento no funciona no me devuelve nada.

Bueno esta seria basicamente mi pregunta espero que alguno me pueda ayudar con esta duda de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente no te funciona porque en el segundo ejemplo estas utilizando una lista, y para ver si un valor esta en la dicha lista lo podemos hacer con `in`, es decir tu `if` quedaría algo así

```
diccionario = {'jorge' : [1,2,3] , 'andrea' : [4,5,6]}

buscar = int(input("Introduce numero: "))

for nombre, numero in diccionario.items():
  if  buscar in numero:
      print(nombre)
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/repls/DryBitterDisc)

Espero que sea lo que estas buscando

Saludos!!!

Comment: Me funciono correctamente eres un crack :) muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado!!!